# jQuery.noConflict weird behavior in userscript, in Firefox only

Tags: jquery, firefox, mootools, greasemonkey, userscripts

I have a userscript containing this:

```
// userscript header
(function() {
    // here is jquery source code
    var $ = $.noConflict();
})();
```

The site I'm using it on, is using mootools, so the site's code depends on `$`. The `noConflict` doesn't help in Firefox (23.0.1) for some weird reason. The site still gets jQuery in $, which breaks site's original functionality.

However, when I change it to:
        var $ = jQuery.noConflict();

It works. Why?

I can't put userscript on jsfiddle, so here is a gif with all the code (HTML on left, userscript on right), showing the problem:

[image: jQuery.noConflict weird behavior]

Versions: everything is latest, Firefox 23.0.1, Greasemonkey 1.11, jQuery v1.10.2, Mootools 1.4.5-nc

"Bug" does not happen in: Chrome 29.0.1547.66m, Opera 12.16

Comment: Have you tried using `jQuery`, instead of `$` ? - `jQuery.noConflict();` and using `jQuery` for the jQuery code instead of `$`

Comment: Didn't have any effect. But it DOES have effect when I change `window.$ instanceof jQuery` (since window.$ isn't instance actually) to `window.$ == jQuery`. Why would that have an effect?

Comment: So `var $ = jQuery.noConflict()` works, while `var $ = $.noConflict()` doesn't. What's the difference? Uh, so apparently `jQuery===$` is FALSE. I've got to research this..

Comment: How exactly are you performing this part? `// here is jquery source code`

Comment: I'm generating userscript based on chrome extension manifest. I just put all content_script files into one big user.js file.

Comment: @Sergio please add your suggestion as answer so I can accept it, thx

Comment: Please leave it open some more time/days. I am not sure either of why, and it might come some good input from people that are not online just now.

Comment: What version of jquery is this?

Comment: latest: jQuery v1.10.2

Comment: Can reproduce now, and found the piece of code in GM that is "responsible" (the no grants code path in [`createSandbox`](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/blob/1.11/components/greasemonkey.js#L69-L93)). No idea yet at to *why* it happens.

Comment: @nmaier Removing line '@run-at document-start' makes it work. Might help in your investigation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see how `noConflict()` is actually implemented...

```
if ( window.$ === jQuery ) {
  window.$ = _$; // where $_ is window.$ before jquery reassigns it.
}
```

Now we need to remember that the `window` the user script operates on is not actually the same thing as the `window` the site sees. It is a sandboxed wrapper instead (at least in Greasemonkey and Scriptish). That wrapper actually hides all "expandos", i.e. added or overwritten properties on the original object.

Hence in your user script `window.$ === undefined` while in the actual page it is defined as that mootools helper. `unsafewindow.$` is also the mootools helper, as [`unsafeWindow`](http://wiki.greasespot.net/UnsafeWindow) is the unwrapped page `window`.

Now, when your userscript includes jQuery, `$` will on be set on the wrapped `window`. The original page `window.$` is still mootools from the perspective of the website.

Next, the call to `.noConflict()`, as implemented above, will revert `window.$` back, but on the sandbox wrapper. Hence `window.$` in the user-script sandbox becomes `undefined` again, while the page `window.$` (aka. `unsafeWindow.$` in the user script sandbox) still is the moo helper (and was actually never changed).

*Update*: Greasemonkey actively disables these wrappers explicitly in their "no-grants" branch of [`createSandox()`](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/blob/1.11/components/greasemonkey.js#L69-L93) by setting `wantXRays = false`. I'd consider this to be [a bug](https://github.com/greasemonkey/greasemonkey/issues/1801).

Now, that's the reason why you need `.noConflict()` in the first place in `GM`.

`var $ = $.noConflict()` cannot work because it is an error. The `var $` will be hoisted and hence it is immediately undefined. jQuery will not actually set it (it just sets `window.$`, not local-scope `$`), and hence the `$.noConflict()` call becomes `undefined.noConflict()`.

Comment: The original site's code crashes after including my userscript (in latest firefox+greasemonkey, but not in opera), so this sentence isn't always right: _"The original page window.$ is still mootools from the perspective of the website."_ (or am I missing something?)

Comment: Yes, that's what I saying (I tested that with Firefox/Scriptish). I cannot dig any deeper without having an actual reproducible example or at least actual error messages. Please update your question accordingly if you want an answer. I should note that I'm a co-author of the Scriptish add-on, so I know a thing or two about GM/Scripish.

Comment: I have updated the question, please check. (I was unable to reproduce the original problem, so I have updated it with something similar what I can reproduce.)

Comment: If I do `var $ = window.$.noConflict()` then it works. So I guess you're right. Thanks for help.

Comment: GM's "no-grants" behavior IS a bug.  One that has wrecked thousands of scripts and caused newbies quite a bit of trouble, while simultaneously helping no one.  Yet, **this was done on purpose!** And, the GM lead developer refuses to acknowledge his huge mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I am not too familiar with jQuery's `noConflict()` method, but I would imagine that it has to be used on the global scope.

You are using it within the scope of an anonymous function, so the `noConflict()` method will not have any effect on the `$` declaration outside this scope.

Move the `$.noConflict()` line into the global scope and you should be fine:

```
$.noConflict();
(function() {
    ...
})();
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be before where he included jQuery? *"`(function() {
    // here is jquery source code`"*